# How to parse/sed multiple string with regex expression

Tags: regex, parsing, sed, string-formatting

I'm trying to extract information from a bounce of ovpn files in order to update my server list. I find a way to extract information with sed and all works, but I'm stuck when I try to extract data to make the directory structure.

What I have is files inside a folder, for example:

```
ch101.tcp443.ovpn
ch101.udp1194.ovpn
ch102.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn
ch102.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn
ch102.tcp443.ovpn
ch102.udp1194.ovpn
```

Now I want to extract information to make directory structure, so [I made a regex](https://regex101.com/r/A6nNyT/3/) to extract all the info I need

It works on all files that I have, and gets data from the name of file. So from "ch101.udp1194.ovpn" it extracts "ch101" and "udp", into groups 1 and 2.

But when I try to make it works with sed I fail. I tried to break it down into steps, but even with only the 1st group looking for "ch101" it doesn't work:

```
echo 'ch101.udp1194.ovpn' | sed -rn 's/^([a-z\-]+\d{1,4})/\1/p'
```

What did I miss? I'm not sed expert but I find similar expression that works but this one don't.

My final purpose is to create directory and store in it all the information that I need, so:

```
for i in /opt/ovpn/*.ovpn ; do 
    [ -f "$i" ] || continue
    FIRST_ARG=$(echo $i | sed ...) # extract ch101
    SECOND_ARG=$(echo $i | sed ...) # extract udp
    FIRST_ARG_TEXT=$(echo $FIRST_ARG | sed ...) # extract text from FIRST_ARG
    FIRST_ARG_NUM=$(echo $FIRST_ARG | sed ...) # extract num from FIRST_ARG
    FIRST_ARG_NUM_4FORMAT=$(printf '%04i\n' $FIRST_ARG_NUM) # 4 digits for FIRST_ARG_NUM

    mkdir /opt/somedir/$FIRST_ARG_TEXT$FIRST_ARG_NUM_4FORMAT$SECOND_ARG
    cp ........
done
```

So from ch101.udp1194.ovpn I'll end with a directory named

```
ch0101udp
```

Maybe is not the best and clean way but to me seems simple and is the max that my knowledge can achieve

Any idea or question is good to me

Ps. I'm under busybox 1.30 so this must be sh not bash

Comment: Sed doesn't support `\d`. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: I tried with echo 'it66.tcp443.ovpn' | sed -rn 's/^([a-z\-]+[0-9]{1,4})/\1/p' with no luck, and with echo 'it66.tcp443.ovpn' | sed -rn 's/^([a-z\-]+[[:digit:]]{1,4})/\1/p' and no luck. I think I'm making it wrong

Comment: @miken32 Can be a good starting point, the problem is when you find this ch-onion1.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn print $2 return nordvpn and not the protocol

Comment: [edit] your question to show, given the sample input you posted, the directory structure you want to end up with in the same way as [tree](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm#examples) would display them after they're created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems: sed does not support a lot of the character class escape sequences like `\d` so you need to specify them as `[0-9]`.

As well, you're trying to replace the matched sequence with itself, so there would be no change in the output. You need to have `.*` to catch the stuff around it.

Something like this would work for your first group:

```
sed -En 's/^([a-z\-]+[0-9]{1,4}).*/\1/p'
```

But really what you should be doing is using a proper program to do this. Not sure if it's available on Busybox but awk could do everything you're looking for:

```
echo 'ch101.udp1194.ovpn' | awk -F. '{a=$1; b=$(NF-1); gsub(/[0-9]/, "", a); gsub(/[0-9]/, "", b); gsub(/^[a-z-]+/, "", $1); printf("%s%04d%s", a, $1, b)}'
```

Output from your sample data:

```
ch0101tcp
ch0101udp
ch0102tcp
ch0102udp
ch0102tcp
ch0102udp
```

---

An explanation:

```
awk -F. '{
    a=$1;                          # assign the first field to a
    b=$(NF-1);                     # assign the second last field to b
    gsub(/[0-9]/, "", a);          # remove numbers from a
    gsub(/[0-9]/, "", b);          # remove numbers from b
    gsub(/^[a-z-]+/, "", $1);      # remove letters from the first field
    printf("%s%04d%s", a, $1, b)   # output in desired format
}'
```

Comment: sed is not necessary if there's any other way that is compatible with BusyBox sh. So I only need to include all rest of the string, if I understand correctly. In this way I can make it work maybe in one single line? Or do you think that became too complex?

Comment: Thanks @miken32, I think this's the cleanest way! I don't know the gsub command but your one line idea is quite good! I do some try to see if catch all, I've over 9k file to parse each time

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ sed -n 's/\([^.]*\).*\.\([^0-9]*\)[^.]*\.[^.]*$/\1\2/p' file
ch101tcp
ch101udp
ch102tcp
ch102udp
ch102tcp
ch102udp

$ echo 'ch-onion1.nordvpn.com.tcp443.ovpn' | sed -n 's/\([^.]*\).*\.\([^0-9]*\)[^.]*\.[^.]*$/\1\2/p'
ch-onion1tcp
```

If so that will work with any sed in any shell on any UNIX box. If not then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide the exact expected output for your various given sample input values.

Comment: Thanks @ed-morton, I think the miken32 solution is quite good. Why is not clear the output? I inserted my final purpose into the request, where I show that I want to extract each piece of data to make the directory structure. If do you think is not clear I can modify it

Comment: I said if what my script is outputting ISN'T what you want then clarify the output but since you asked - you provided 7 input values in your question but only 1 output value and you said you have a regexp that does what you want but your online demo shows that `ch101.udp1194.ovpn` would become `ch101udp` while the text in your question shows that it would become `ch0101udp` (extra `0` added). So the combination of 2 different outputs and not showing the list of outputs in your question for the sample inputs in your question muddies the waters.